# MVC DropDownListFor ViewData Selected Item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get the selected value of a drop down list to default to 3600, if the value is 0. Unfortunately, the drop down defaults to the first option. I believe the selection fails because nothing in the list matches 0. Here is my code:

Controller method:

```
    public void GetTaskInterval(JMASettings model)
    {
        IList<SelectListItem> ilSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Dictionary<string, string> secondsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        secondsDictionary.Add("Every Thirty Minutes", "1800");
        secondsDictionary.Add("Every Hour", "3600");
        secondsDictionary.Add("Every Three Hours", "10800");
        secondsDictionary.Add("Every Day", "86400");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in secondsDictionary)
        {
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
            item.Text = pair.Key;
            item.Value = pair.Value;

            if (model.TaskInterval == 0 && item.Value.ToString() == "3600")
                item.Selected = true;

            if (item.Value == model.TaskInterval.ToString())
                item.Selected = true;

            ilSelectList.Add(item);
        }

        ViewData["TaskInterval"] = ilSelectList;
    }
```

.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JMASettings.TaskInterval, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["TaskInterval"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set default value with `DropDownListFor()` helper you should understand that it is respect value of first argument `model.JMASettings.TaskInterval` in your case.

So you should just check that you put right value to this model property in your `Controller`.

Comment: I decided to use Html.DropDownList("JMASettings.TaskInterval"). When you use a view model and there is a sub class, you must insert the name and then a period.

Comment: @JosephAnderson that'a also acceptable, but i recommend you to use always strondly tuped approach. Becouse it will be easier to change model then, and therefor to maintain your project in future.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SelectList` and put the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` into it:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> secondsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        secondsDictionary.Add("Every Thirty Minutes", "1800");
        secondsDictionary.Add("Every Hour", "3600");
        secondsDictionary.Add("Every Three Hours", "10800");
        secondsDictionary.Add("Every Day", "86400");

var itemlist = new SelectList(secondsDictionary, "Key" , "Value", 3600);
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JMASettings.TaskInterval, itemlist , "Select one")
```

the default value has been set to `3600` but you can change it.

God luck !:)